# Sequence following percentage

Tags: algorithm, statistics

Problem statement: A person has to go to set of locations in a sequence:
Seq: L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 (assume L1, L2 are locations)

But he followed went to locations in different sequence:
ActualSeq: L3 L1 L2 L4 L5 L6

Now I need to find out what is the % sequence followed. Remember, the algo should consider that L4, L5, L6 still were after L3. So it is not a simple % question.

Anyhelp is highly appreciated

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: What is the expected answer for the example you provided? Because for me, L3 is the most displaced location in the list. If you consider "L1 L2 L4 L5 L6", the person followed 83.33% of the sequence.

Comment: Even I don't know the answer and I am suppose to come up with answer and reasoning, till now I like your answer most of Longest Increasing Subsequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem known as [Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) and there are `O(n log n)` algorithms for it.

To find the percentage, you just have to find `LIS(V)/length(V)`.

Here's an example implementation (`O(n^2)`) in Python

**EDIT: changed the code to clearly point where an O(n) step can be turned into O(log n)**

```py
def LIS(V):
    n = len(V)
    T = [0]*(n+1)

    L = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        #this step can be a binary search
        j = max(j for j in xrange(L+1) if j==0 or V[T[j]] < V[i])

        T[j+1] = i
        L = max(L, j+1)

    return L/float(n)*100

print '{:.2f}%'.format(LIS([3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6])) #83.33%
print '{:.2f}%'.format(LIS([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])) #100.00%
print '{:.2f}%'.format(LIS([6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3])) #50.00%
```

Comment: I found an interesting use case, let us assume he had to go 1, 2, but he followed 2,1. In that case LIS gives 50%, should not it be 0%

Comment: @RachitJain LIS only gives the longest increasing subsequence. A sequence with only one element is an increasing sequence, strictly speaking. If you want to force cases with only one element to be treated as 0%, I suggest you using  `(L-1)/float(n-1)*100` instead. But this will also change the value of other sequences. `3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6` for example would be 80% (4/5), instead of 83.33%.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the [Longest common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of the two inputs (Initial Sequence and Actual Sequence)

Divide the longest common subsequence by the number of Locations to get the % sequence followed.

In your case it is 5/6 = .8333 = 83.33%

Comment: LCS is also a good idea. I only like LIS the most because there are `O(n log n)` LIS algorithms, while only `O(n^2)` LCS ones. And LCS is needed only if there may be repetitions in the expected sequence (where there can be ambiguity on the expected position of an element).

Comment: Shankar you are right, but in my case there is no repetition due to the locations. @Juan, very well said about performance parameter

Answer (score 0):

I would try testing the distance between each successive location in the array of locations, like this, using your example:

```
distance from L1 to L2 = 1
distance from L2 to L3 = 2
distance from L3 to L4 = 3
distance from L4 to L5 = 1
distance from L5 to L6 = 1

then add them up...TTL = 8

A perfect, 100% score is 5
Our score is 8

The difference between our score and a perfect score is 8-5 = 3
The percentage is subtracted from 100% like so: 1.00 - 3/5 = 0.40 = 40%
```

Comment: Of course we cannot say 40% of the sequence is followed in above data (or even not followed). So this is not correct.